# How to print output data inside the loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, printing

In the following code user will enter single integer N as number of pairs and then `N` pair as `b`.

```
4
r 1
a 1
a 2
a 1
```

`r` means remove associated number of pair and `a` means add the associated number into list. Code should print(empty!) if the list is empty and if not print the median of list in each iteration. The correct output should be like this:

```
empty!
1
1.5
1
```

but my code outputs the result after each input that users enters,  like below:

```
4

r 1
empty!

a 1
1

a 2
1.5

a 1
1
```

```
import statistics
N = int(input())
B=[]
for i in range(N):
  b = (input().split())
  action, value = b
  if action == 'a':
    B.append(int(value))
    
  elif action == 'r':
    try:
      B.remove(int(value))     
    except ValueError:
      pass
 
  if len(B) == 0:
        print('empty!') 
  else:        
    print(statistics.median(B))
```

Comment: Instead of printing, you could add the results to a list and print it after the input loop finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like that. Firstly store your input tuples in B list. And then with another tempList, you can evaluate your desired output.

```
import statistics

N = int(input())
B = []
for i in range(N):
    b = (input().split())
    action, value = b
    B.append((action, int(value)))
tempList = []
for action, value in B:
    if action == 'a':
        tempList.append(value)

    elif action == 'r':
        try:
            tempList.remove(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    if len(tempList) == 0:
        print('empty!')
    else:
        print(statistics.median(tempList))
```

```
 4
 r 1
 a 1
 a 2
 a 1
 empty!
 1
 1.5
 1
```